# Powershell Invoke-Command with hyphen arguments

Tags: powershell, msdeploy, invoke-command

I need to be able to run the following cmd command on a remote computer.

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package="\\Server\Share\Package.zip" -dest:auto,computerName=Server1
```

Powershells Invoke-Command looks promising but I cannot figure out how to pass the arguments to msdeploy.

I've tried

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName RemoteServer1 -ScriptBlock { "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package="\\Server\Share\Package.zip" -dest:auto,computerName=Server1 }
```

But it says "you must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '-' operator.".
So I'm guessing the issue is the hyphens but I don't know how to escape them to make the command work.

Comment: What PowerShell version are you using?

Comment: The reason I ask is because in PowerShell 4.0 I can run the following script block with no issues both locally and using Invoke-command, and it has a hyphen in it. `$sb = { svn log C:\src -l5 }; &$sb`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Part one: dealing with PowerShell command-line specifics

Use `&` to call external executable. Syntax: `& "[path] command" [arguments]`.

Also note, that msdeploy supports [alternate way of specifying arguments](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569106.aspx) when called from PowerShell:

> With a minor modification to its usual syntax, Web Deploy commands can
>   be run from a Windows PowerShell prompt. To do this, change the colon
>   character (:) after the verb, source, and dest arguments of the Web
>   Deploy command to an equal sign (=). In the following example, compare
>   the Web Deploy command with its PowerShell version.
>
> Web Deploy command:
>
> `command: msdeploy -verb:sync -source:metakey=/lm/w3svc/1 -dest:metakey=/lm/w3svc/2 -verbose`
>
> PowerShell command:
>
> `.\msdeploy.exe -verb=sync -source=metakey=/lm/w3svc/1 -dest=metakey=/lm/w3svc/2 -verbose`

Note, that arguments are wrapped in the array: this hints PowerShell how to pass them correctly to the target application.

Example:

```powershell
Invoke-Command -ComputerName RemoteServer1 -ScriptBlock {&"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" @('-verb=sync', '-source=package="\\Server\Share\Package.zip"', '-dest=auto,computerName=Server1')}
```

#### Part two: dealing with [multi-hop authentication](http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/powershell-2-0-remoting-guide-part-12-%E2%80%93-using-credssp-for-multi-hop-authentication/)

From your comments I'm seeing that now PowerShell successfully runs `msdeploy` on remote server, but `msdeploy` can't access the remote share:

> While the command executes, now msdeploy it saying:
>
> "More Information: Object of type 'package' and path '\Server\Share\Package.zip' cannot be created. Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXCEPTION_WHILE_CREATING_OBJECT.
>
> Error: The Zip package '\Server\Share\Package.zip' could not be loaded. Error: Access to the path '\Server\Share\Package.zip' is denied. Error count: 1."
>
> Even though the user has access to the share (read/write).

That's because you actually trying to establish a remoting session from computer A (client) to computer B (server) and then from computer B, you trying to access the file in a share on computer C (`\\Server\Share\Package.zip`).

[image: CredSSP example]

`Invoke-Command` fails because remote session tries to access the file share using the machine credentials instead of the credentials used to invoke the remote session. [There is a way to pass or delegate credentials from the client](http://www.ravichaganti.com/blog/powershell-2-0-remoting-guide-part-12-%E2%80%93-using-credssp-for-multi-hop-authentication/) so that we can authenticate to the file share. This is what is called multi-hop authentication and PowerShell remoting enables this using CredSSP.

To enable CredSSP, run those commands from elevated prompt:

- On your PC: `Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client -DelegateComputer
  "TargetServer.FQ.DN"`

  `DelegateComputer` parameter is used to specify the server or servers that receive the delegated credentials from the client. The `DelegateComputer` accepts wildcards (`*.FQ.DN`). You can also specify `*` to specify all computers in the network.
- On target server: `Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server`

Now, you should be able to run `Invoke-Command` with CredSSP as the authentication method and pass the credentials:

```powershell
Invoke-Command -ComputerName RemoteServer1 -Authentication Credssp -Credential Domain\Username -ScriptBlock {&"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" @('-verb=sync', '-source=package="\\Server\Share\Package.zip"', '-dest=auto,computerName=Server1')}
```

#### Part three: passing parameters with Invoke-Command

> How would I go about having the server parameterized. If I have a parameter `$Server` as the server name, how would I go about putting that in as a replacement for the `-dest=auto,computerName=Server1` part?

To pass arguments to a scriptblock, use `ArgumentList` parameter:

```powershell
$Servers = @('Server1', 'Server2', 'Server3')
$Command = {
    Param($Srv)
    &"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" @('-verb=sync', '-source=package="\\Server\Share\Package.zip"', "-dest=auto,computerName=$Srv")
}

$Servers |
    ForEach-Object {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName RemoteServer1 -Authentication Credssp -Credential Domain\Username -ScriptBlock $Command -ArgumentList $_
    }
```

And going further:

> Нow would I go about adding extra parameters dynamically to the command. I need to add in `-skip:objectName=dirPath,absolutePath="<folder>"` to the arguments in the `&"C:\Program Files\..."` line, for each folder in an array of strings.

If you have one set of folders to exclude for all servers:

```powershell
$Servers = @('Server1', 'Server2', 'Server3')
$SkipPaths = @('C:\folder\to\skip1', 'C:\folder\to\skip2', 'C:\folder\to\skip3')

$SkipCmd = $SkipPaths | ForEach-Object {"-skip=objectName=dirPath,absolutePath=$_"}

$Command = {
    Param($Srv, $Skp)
    &"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" $(@('-verb=sync', '-source=package="\\Server\Share\Package.zip"', "-dest=auto,computerName=$Srv") + $Skp)
}

$Servers |
    ForEach-Object {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName RemoteServer1 -Authentication Credssp -Credential Domain\Username -ScriptBlock $Command -ArgumentList ($_, $SkipCmd)
    }
```

If you have different set of folders for each of servers:

```powershell
$Servers = @{
    Server1 = @('C:\folder\to\skip_1', 'C:\folder\to\skip_2', 'C:\folder\to\skip_3')
    Server2 = @('C:\folder\to\skip_A', 'C:\folder\to\skip_B', 'C:\folder\to\skip_C')
    Server3 = @('C:\folder\to\skip_X', 'C:\folder\to\skip_Y', 'C:\folder\to\skip_Z')
}

$Command = {
    Param($Srv, $Skp)
    &"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" $(@('-verb=sync', '-source=package="\\Server\Share\Package.zip"', "-dest=auto,computerName=$Srv") + $Skp)
}

$Servers.GetEnumerator() |
    ForEach-Object {
        $SkipCmd = $_.Value | ForEach-Object {"-skip=objectName=dirPath,absolutePath=$_"}
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName RemoteServer1 -Authentication Credssp -Credential Domain\Username -ScriptBlock $Command -ArgumentList ($_.Key, $SkipCmd)
    }
```

Comment: It does not appear to work. When executing in powershell it just shows >> on a new line. And when I check the location where msdeploy should have populated it is empty.

Comment: I've updated my answer, could you try again? This time, the arguments for msdeploy are wrapped in array - it's another PS way to pass tricky command lines. I've checked it on my servers now and it's works.

Comment: While the command executes, now msdeploy it saying: "More Information: Object of type 'package' and path '\\Server\Share\Package.zip' cannot be created.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXCEPTION_WHILE_CREATING_OBJECT.
Error: The Zip package '\\Server\Share\Package.zip' could not be loaded.
Error: Access to the path '\\Server\Share\Package.zip' is denied.
Error count: 1." Even though the user has access to the share (read/write).

Comment: Sounds like multi-hop auth issue, I've updated my answer, see if it helps.

Comment: its working great now. Just once last thing, how would I go about having the server parameterized. if i have a parameter $server as the server name, how would i go about putting that in as a replacement for the '-dest=auto,computerName=Server1' part?

Comment: Considering you helped so much before, how would I go about adding extra parameters dynamically to the command. I need to add in -skip:objectName=dirPath,absolutePath="<folder>" to the arguments in the &"C:\Program Files\..." line, for each folder in an array of strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Powershell's [stop parsing operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847892.aspx) (`--%`):

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName RemoteServer1 -ScriptBlock { 
    "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" --% -verb:sync -source:package="\\Server\Share\Package.zip" -dest:auto,computerName=Server1 
}
```

You'll need to have new lines in there, however, to stop the stop parsing and close the script block.  The other drawback is that, obviously, you can't put variables after the operator and expect them to expand to their value.

Comment: That does not appear to work. Powershell just gives the following error "You must provide a value expression on the right-hand side of the '%' operator."

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I missed the part where this was required to execute on a remote computer. The answer below doesn't help in that case, but it's still relevant for other folks so I'll leave it.*

There are a bunch of different ways to invoke an .exe in PowerShell and each one has it's own drawbacks. From all the methods that I've tried the following has worked the best for invoking msdeploy.exe.

You can get latest sources in my gist at https://gist.github.com/sayedihashimi/1390cd6c97f25eefabdc. I've pasted it below.

```
function Execute-CommandString{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string[]]$command,

        [switch]
        $ignoreExitCode
    )
    process{
        foreach($cmdToExec in $command){
            'Executing command [{0}]' -f $cmdToExec | Write-Verbose
            cmd.exe /D /C $cmdToExec

            if(-not $ignoreExitCode -and ($LASTEXITCODE -ne 0)){
                $msg = ('The command [{0}] exited with code [{1}]' -f $cmdToExec, $LASTEXITCODE)
                throw $msg
            }
        }
    }
}

# in this case there is no space in any argument and the call to msdeploy.exe succeeds
$msdeployExe = 'C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe'
$packOutput = 'C:\temp\publish\01'
$pubOut = 'c:\temp\publish-no-space\'

$publishArgs = @()
$publishArgs += ('-source:contentPath=''{0}''' -f "$packOutput")
$publishArgs += ('-dest:contentPath=''{0}''' -f "$pubOut")
$publishArgs += '-verb:sync'
$publishArgs += '-disablerule:BackupRule'

'Calling msdeploy to publish to file system with the command: [{0} {1}]' -f $msdeployExe,($publishArgs -join ' ') | Write-Output
$command = '"{0}" {1}' -f $msdeployExe,($publishArgs -join ' ')
Execute-CommandString -command $command

# in this case the call to msdeploy.exe fails with an argument error 
$pubOut2 = 'c:\temp\publish with space\'
$publishArgs2 = @()
$publishArgs2 += ('-source:contentPath=''{0}''' -f "$packOutput")
$publishArgs2 += ('-dest:contentPath=''{0}''' -f "$pubOut2")
$publishArgs2 += '-verb:sync'
$publishArgs2 += '-disablerule:BackupRule'

'Calling msdeploy to publish to file system with the command: [{0} {1}]' -f $msdeployExe,($publishArgs -join ' ') | Write-Output

$command = '"{0}" {1}' -f $msdeployExe,($publishArgs2 -join ' ')
Execute-CommandString -command $command
```

Here I quote the path to msdeploy.exe with `"` and I escape any paths using `'` withing the arguments.

I own the Visual Studio web publish experience and for ASP.NET 5 we are going to be calling msdeploy.exe from PowerShell. This is the technique we are currently using for this.

Comment: That does not appear to execute msdeploy on a remote computer. The reason I'm trying to execute the command on a remote computer is because there is a WAN between me and the remote computer, which causes the msdeploy to be extremely slow.

Comment: Oops sorry I missed that part. I've updated the answer to indicate that it doesn't help in that case. Sorry about that.